# QMake: how do scopes work?

Tags: qt, qmake

For some weird reason I can't get scopes in QMake to work. Here's some code in my project file:

```
debug {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += -g3 -O0
    message ("Some debug output")
}

release {
    DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG
    DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
    message ("No debug output")
}
```

But when I compile it in debug mode, here's the gcc command line I get:

```
g++ -c -g -g3 -O0 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DLIBPROVERIM_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT -DWINDOWS -DQT_DLL -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"c:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include\QtCore" -I"c:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include\QtNetwork" -I"c:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include\QtGui" -I"c:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include\QtXml" -I"c:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include\QtSql" -I"c:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include" -I"c:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"..\proverim" -I"." -I"c:\Qt\2010.05\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\PForm.o ..\proverim\PForm.cc
```

Note that I tried cleaning my project, as well as manually removing makefiles. Now why does it take defines from both scopes? Also, I don't see any messages, where are they supposed to be?

Comment: I didn't mention: my platform is MS Windows XP with Qt Creator 2.0.1 and Qt 4.7.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. To solve it I used the CONFIG "function" instead of the scopes.
That section of your .pro file would be:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += -g3 -O0
message("DEBUG!")
} else {
DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG
DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
message("RELEASE!")
}
```

Tried it in a simple "HelloWorld" project and everything seemed to work fine.

Comment: This worked, thanks! Still, I find this syntax a bit otherworldy.

Answer (score 1):

There is another config option called [debug_and_release](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmake-variable-reference.html#config) which allows you to build both modes simultaneously. In that case, it's correct that both of your scopes are getting triggered.

Try adding `CONFIG=debug` to your initial qmake command; it should override any automatic defaults and limit you to debug mode.

As a debugging measure, you could also try outputting the entire contents of CONFIG via `message($$CONFIG)` in your .pro file. The messages are printed when qmake is run, not when the makefiles are compiled.

Comment: Thanks, now I see the messages. When I run with CONFIG=debug, proper scopes get executed, however, I'm getting a lot of missing headers
 like QtCore/qglobal.h. I also tried CONFIG-=release, but that didn't do anything :(

Comment: try "CONFIG -= debug_and_release"